# WSO2: Address Endpoint seems to overwrite wsa:To WS-Addressing property

Tags: web-services, soap, endpoint, ws-addressing, wso2-esb

Forwarding a SOAP message from WSO2ESB via another ESB to a backend web-service does not seem possible, because the original `wsa:To` value is modified to the URL of the intermediate ESB.
The following configuration shows this behavior:

```
<header name="To" value="http://ws.backend.com/service"/>
<property name="PRESERVE_WS_ADDRESSING" value="true"/>
<send>
    <endpoint name="IntermediateESB">
        <address uri="http://esb.intermediate.com/proxy">
            <enableAddressing/>
        </address>
    </endpoint>
</send>
```

The SOAP header now contains the following `wsa:To`:

```
<wsa:To>http://esb.intermediate.com/proxy</wsa:To>
```

The `address uri` seems to overwrite the original `wsa:To` value.

This will fail in the intermediate ESB, because it expects the URL of the backend web-service in `wsa:To`.
The SOAP header should have contained the following for the intermediate ESB to work properly:

```
<wsa:To>http://ws.backend.com/service</wsa:To>
```

What configuration is possible to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your backend address in wsa:ReplyTo header tag. So your intermediate will proceed the response to backend service.

```
<header name="ReplyTo" value="http://ws.backend.com/service"/>
```

More info :  http://www.w3.org/Submission/ws-addressing/

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but this is not what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you have to build the WS-Addressing headers yourself explicitly, and not use `<enableAddressing/>`!

Example:

```
<header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" name="wsa:To" value="http://ws.backend.com/service"/>
<header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" name="wsa:MessageID" expression="get-property('MessageID')"/>
<header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" name="wsa:Action" value="http://ws.backend.com/operation"/>
<header name="To" value="http://esb.intermediate.com/proxy"/>
<header name="Action" value="http://ws.backend.com/operation"/>
<property name="PRESERVE_WS_ADDRESSING" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<send>
    <endpoint name="IntermediateESB">
        <address uri="http://esb.intermediate.com/proxy"/>
    </endpoint>
</send>
```

Note that you have to set 'Action' twice with the same value.
Also note that you can use 'To' with a different value, and use a 'default' endpoint instead of the 'address' endpoint above.

The SOAP message is posted to 'http://esb.intermediate.com/proxy', and the WS-Addressing headers are:

```
<wsa:To xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://ws.backend.com/service</wsa:To>
<wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:52aad1f4-9295-43f6-90c0-304e87922c27</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:Action xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://ws.backend.com/operation</wsa:Action>
```

The 'IntermediateESB' can now forward this SOAP message to 'http://ws.backend.com/service'.